# "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided." when I want to signup user

Tags: django, flutter, jwt, xampp, abstractuser

when I want to post data and create a new teacher it gives me this error and I don't know what to do please help me

this is my models.py
[image]

this is my views.py
[image]

this is my serializer.py
[image]

Comment: Please paste code instead of uploading images of code, see how do I ask a good question [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit your **settings.py** and add this :

```
  REST_FRAMEWORK = {
   'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
       'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
   ),
   'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser'
   ),
}
```

But have look for better insight https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/